# API patch and put doesn't update version field

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ecmascript-6

I'm currently trying to build an application with Node.js as the back end.

After asking around about what API method to use for an update since I was originally using post for all, I started using put and patch
the problem is put and the patch doesn't update the version field in my DB.

Is something wrong with the way I'm calling put and patch or that's just how they are

```
router.patch('/update/:id', async (req, res) => {
    // get category id
    const id = req.params.id;
    // check if category is found
    try {
        const category = await Category.findByIdAndUpdate(id, req.body);
        // check if no category is found
        if (!category) {
            return res.status(400).send('Category not found');
        }
        // return category
        return res.status(200).send(category);
    }
    catch (err) {
        return res.status(400).send(err);
    }
});
```

[before update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufQMQ.png)

[after update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPtbC.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add this to your Category schema :

```
schema.pre('update', function( next ) {
  this.update({}, { $inc: { __v: 1 } }, next );
});
```

Comment: i figured out that .save() could have solved that but this also works perfectly fine ty and sorry for late replay

Answer (score 0):

`__v` will be automatically increased by Mongoose when it is necessary. It is used internally by Mongoose, so you don't have to increase it when updating document. This value is atomically incremented whenever a modification to an array potentially changes any array’s elements position. It will be applied on operations: `$pull`, `$pullAll`, `$pop`, `$set` of an entire array.

Comment: i figured out the issue, i needed to save after the update .